# my before_create isn't working even though my method returns nil.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

This is my user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  before_save :valid_email?

  validates :username, presence: true,
                       uniqueness: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true

  enum role: [ :flyer, :admin ]

  def valid_email?
    email_checker
  end

  private

  def email_checker
    self.email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+$/)
  end

end
```

This is my test:

```
test "if a user has an invalid email, cannot be saved" do
    user = build(:user)
    user1 = build(:user, email: "here@here@here")
    user2 = build(:user, email: "here.here@here")

    assert user.save
    refute user1.save
    refute user2.save
  end
```

The email_checker method does return nil if email is either here@here@here or here.here@here. So what is going on?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen? It works exactly as it is written. Do you want to prevent model saving if it is not valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you just call `self.email.match` method. If you want to validate filed you should use or create validator.

In your case you can create [own custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) or use e-mail validator from gems (i.e [email_validator](https://github.com/balexand/email_validator)).

Comment: Ah thanks... I need to make a custom validator. That makes a lot of sense. I incorrectly thought that the before_create and before_save callbacks were validating... but they are clearly not. REad up on this and fixed it.